# Как в чистом JS, найти родителя элемента по классу?

Tags: javascript

Решаю задачу и из за неопытности и незнания застрял в одном месте.
Суть задачи заключается в том, что необходимо по нажатию мышкой на одном элементе страницы (маленький крестик закрытия небольшого списка из вкладок - вроде записной книжки) удалить родителя этого элемента.

Это удачно получается сделать так `target.parentNode.remove();`

Однако задача в том, что нужен универсальный код для случая неизвестной вложенности т.е. мой элемент на который происходит клик может быть очень глубоко вложен.

JS

```
newLi.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
            let target = event.target; 
            if (!target.classList.contains('fa')) return;

            target.parent.classList.contains('new'); // Неудачная попытка

        });
```

HTML

```
<template id='template'>
    <li class="tameplate new-todo new">
        <p id="inputText"></p>
        <i class="fa fa-times spin" id="spin"></i>
    </li>
</template>
```

Там где комментарий "неудачная попытка" я попробовал применить то, что нашёл в сети видимо сделал это неправильно, **подскажите как это сделать правильно?**
В html коде элемент по которому кликают это **i** возможно его нужно будет глубже поместить оградив div или многими div, поэтому нужно чтобы находился родитель например по классу "new".

Comment: Используйте `target.closest('Имя родителя')`

Comment: Как все сложно на чистом js то, когда решается буквально одной строчкой jq :(

Comment: @Crus надеюсь ты не серьезно это? Или ты пользуешься ES2?

Comment: Не туда написал. ) Хотел написать к нижней функции в ответе. )

Comment: @Crus там всё равно чисто полифилл метода, который применять не нужно, если нет ориентира на древний IE. Всё решается одной строчкой кода

Answer (score 2):

Можно такой функцией:

```
function closest(el, selector) {
    if (Element.prototype.closest) {
      return el.closest(selector);
    }

    let parent = el;

    while (parent) {
      if (parent.matches(selector)) {
        return parent;
      }

      parent = parent.parentElement;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

и далее используем проверку

```
if (closest($el, '.selector')) { // code }
```

Comment: спасибо, однако этот способ ещё достаточно сложен для меня и я не могу ещё его понять.

Comment: @Mark это polyfill из документации по методу `closest` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest . ПО сути, можно не боятся использовать сам метод без такой портянки кода

Answer (score 1):

```
target.closest('.new').remove();
```

Нахожу прямо по классу, даже если обернуть `i` в `<div>`